# How to associate a filetype with a Windows program installed in Wine

Tags: command-line, wine, file-association

I have a doubt. I don't know how to associate a filetype with a Windows program installed in Wine.

I am trying for a few hours... Nothing works to me.

I'm running Ubuntu since one week ago.

I am a rookie in the Terminal and I don't understand how to apply this FAQ information. I don't know how to write this commands in the terminal. Can someone helps me, please?

I want to associate xsc files to the Transcribe program (/home/joan/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Transcribe/Transcribe.exe)

Below I attach the FAQ answer that I am trying to follow

Edit:  I am using ubuntu 18.04.
 I've tried installing Ubuntu tweaks (maybe not the right version... is not working to me the option of change file associations).
I've tried go to an .xsc file, propierties, open with... (and my program is not there).
And also I tried a lot of "command-line solutions", which are not working to me, because I can't understand it.

[FAQ Wine answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV0Sy.png)

Comment: "Nothing works for me" is too vague. Have you tried anything? If so, what have you tried? What leads you to believe that it didn't work? What were the errors? Do you know how to make the .reg file that the FAQ talks about? Do you know what to do with the .reg file after you have made it? Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, is my fist time in a forum.

Thanks for your response.

I am using ubuntu 18.04

I've tried installing Ubuntu tweaks (maybe not the right version... is not working to me the option of change file associations)

I've tried go to an .xsc file, propierties, open with... (and my program is not there)

And also I tried a lot of "command-line solutions", which are not working to me, because I can't understand it.

Comment: The FAQ seems very clear on what you must do: Create a "xsc.reg" file just like the "pdf.reg" example. You should not need tweaks or obscure shell incantations. Follow the instructions in the FAQ. If you reach an instruction that you don't understand, tell us exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Ok, let's go.

I am in the regedit, and I go to the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

Now I can't find a folder with my desired filetype (.xsc).

Also, I can't understand what should I do afterwards... I'm so sorry, but everything is new for me.

Thanks for your help! I really appreciate that

Comment: The instructions did not say to go into regedit. The instructions said to create a new empty file (on your desktop or anyplace convenient), and to fill the content of that file with the example they provided.

Comment: Ok, then I wrote the following: 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xsc]
@="XSCfile"
"Content Type"="application/xsc"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\XSCfile\Shell\Open\command]
@="winebrowser \"%1\"" 

Then I create the xcs.reg and I put that in the folder Home.

I run this command (regedit $HOME/pdf.reg).

And nothing happens...

Can you help me, please?
Thanks for everything!